# Best Android Phone for Development?

Tags: android

I am interested in starting Android development, I have significant experience with .NET and WP7 development with several applications on the WP7 Marketplace and a couple on the iPhone App Store.  What is the best Android (and cheapest) device to get so that I can test my Android applications on,  I realize there is an emulator but in my experience its a pretty big difference from emulator to device when testing comes and performance.

I also understand there is some fragmenetation concerns around Android, is there any guidance around how to programatically handle these issues? Such as tips/tricks?

Update: I forgot to mention to the phone needs to be unlocked.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964788/is-it-worth-purchasing-google-android-dev-phone

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for info on supporting multiple screens.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I tried searching Stackoverflow before asking this to avoid duplicating but didn't find anything...

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the answers address the most important issue (for me): something that spits out logcat reliably.  All the devices I have seem to provide logcat to Eclipse very unreliably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Nexus is the most developer friendly phone

If you want more than one and a representative handset of most of the major groupings these phones should help

Google Nexus - vanilla Android has access to the latest APIs quickest - large screen

HTC Hero - HTC Sense UI and medium sized screen

Sony X10 / mini - Has Sonys Rachael ui, timescape and mediascape, mini has a small size screen

Motorola Droid - Very popular in the US, hardware keyboard

Also take a look at Cyanogenmod

For knowing which api to target keep an eye on this http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html
and for screen sizes
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Comment: "Google Nexus" is not a phone.. you probably mean the Nexus One, or the new Nexus S.

Comment: i think we all know what he means. great answer by the way! good round up of a broad range of options. I'm keeping this in mind when I consider purchasing other handsets to test.

Comment: By Nexus I did mean either the nexus one or the nexus s assuming that is developer friendly as the one has been, I fully imagine it will be and certainly looking forward to it!

Answer (score 3):

The Nexus S is worth the investment. It is the only Android phone with new sensors including:
3 axis GYROSCOPE, Near Field Communication (NFC), Gingerbread Android 2.3, Proximity Sensor, Light Sensor.

It is officially endorsed by Google. The Nexus One was an excellent phone, so its likely that the Nexus S will be too.

As for fragmentation, the Android market collects bug reports, but they fail to gather machine level data about which device is causing the bug. For this, I recommend http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/

Comment: I looked at this phone, and it looks great.  However, can it be purchased for cheap unlocked? I am thinking it will be around 600 dollars if its unlocked...

Comment: Once you are a registered Android developer ($25, no Big Brother) You will instantly be granted access to official, unlocked, Android dev phones here: http://android.brightstarcorp.com/index.htm The Nexus S is not yet on there, but it will be in a matter of weeks. I highly recommend you wait for it, as unlocking the phone through any other way instantly voids any warranty from Samsung and Google

Answer (score 1):

I'd get a Nexus One from Google which comes unlocked and usually is the first model to get access to new Android releases.

Comment: As will the soon-to-be-released Nexus S from what I understand (and hope...)

Comment: that would be my advice if you looked for the best android device. i do not know which one to recommend for cheapest price.

Comment: Note that not all Nexus One is an Android Developer Phone, although both Nexus One and ADP are sold unlocked. See developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 0):

others have answered your concern about the best android device for development, this post is going to focus about the best practice with dealing with different hardwares.

The typical problem when dealing with different hardware is you have different screen sizes and different hardware capability. For screen size, you can easily handle them by externalizing your UI as much as possible to the XML based layout description language. Android will automatically choose the correct XML file when you provide different UI layout resource files.

Android Market also supports filtering of applications based in hardware capability, if your device needs accelerometer you can set in your application so that your application will not be shown to users that don't have an accelerometer, etc.

Android makes it relatively easy to handle fragmentation, as long as you take some care.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus S for sure it comes out tomorrow, new flagship dev phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cheap one, a low end performer with a small screen, the Samsung Galaxy Europa is a good deal (no multitouch though) Has Swype keyboard which is great fun.