# hierarchy is not working for my device

Tags: android

when I run hierarchy in terminal. it can show the interface of it, but can not connect to my device.And it can connect to virtual emulator. It remind me in terminal like that,

1. Adb rejected forward command for device 172.18...... unknown host service
2. missing forward port for 172.18.....
3. unable to get view server protocal version from device 172.18....

How can it show my view structure of my device in the hierarchy viewer. Can anyone help me ?or 
anyone who knows where to find the knowledge of the hierarchy. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

HierarchyViewer doesn't work on production builds for security reasons. I wrote an API that lets you use HierarchyViewer on any device with your app: https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

Comment: thank you , I have tried your method.As I am a fresh android engineer. it seems too complex for me. But thanks all the same.

Comment: is this the same issue ? 
00:47:21 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 015d....
[2013-06-13 00:47:21 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 015d......
[2013-06-13 00:47:21 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: asus-nexus_7-015d.....

Comment: @Romain Guy can you please explain a bit more about what is the production builds? Thanks!

Comment: @Nativ he was talking about production builds of Android system, I suppose.

Comment: hmmm. Genymotion works with hierarchyViewer without any modifications to source code. I wonder if there is a simpler way to get this working with debug builds that has surfaced since this post back in 2011?

Comment: @Romain Guy I just copy ViewServer.java class in my Application package.  Is that enough?

Comment: See my reply below.  There are instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html that explain how to get the View Server working in a development environment on an unlocked android device.

Comment: The documentation says Android 4.1 and newer versions don't require using ViewServer, but Hierarchy Viewer didn't work with my Android 5.0 device (ANDROID_HVPROTO was set up) until I added ViewServer to the app.

Answer (score 23):

For anyone working with Android 4.1 or later: you can get Hierarchy Viewer working by setting the environment variable `ANDROID_HVPROTO` to `ddm`.

Mac OSX/Android Studio users, remember to start hierarchy viewer from command line so it will pick up the environment variable. If you installed it with Android Studio, you can find it in `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools`

https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html

Comment: command to launch Android Device Monitor: `tools/monitor` (Hierarchy Viewer is a part of ADM)

Answer (score 19):

Romain's ViewServer project (see answer #1) works great for this.  I downloaded the code, turned the project into a library project, added a dependency in my app to the new library project, and changed my app's base Activity class to subclass from this simple class:

```
public class SimpleViewServerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);
    }
}
```

Now I can connect from the Android Debug Monitor's Hierarchy View and debug my layout.

Comment: Tried to download and open the project, says: project uses unsupported grandle version. I have the most recent version of Android Studio and Grandle. Any way to fix this or the link can be concidere dead now? (since it doens't work and Hierarchy viewer is dead as well)

Comment: @h3d0 Just replace the gradle wrapper with a more recent version, or configure AS to use a custom gradle distribution and ignore the gradle wrapper

Answer (score 3):

Hierarchy viewer worked for me once I selected 
Tools-->Android-->Enable ADB Integration within Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found an answer at http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html.  There is an environmental variable that needs to be set in your development environment before the ViewServer will connect.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3.
The conclusion is at the end of this post.

Notation: 
    Monitor = Android Device Monitor
    Studio = Android Studio

In the Android Studio’s preference -> (Build, Execution, Deployment) -> Instant Run -> uncheck Instant Run. Otherwise, it will prompt error message “Application Installation Failed”, and I tried  several ways without unchecking Instant Run, but none of them works. So just Uncheck Instant Run for now.

(i) If it’s production build(Run ‘app’):

(1) If I put a check mark on “Enable ADB Integration” option from the drop down menu from “Tools”:

(a) Opening Monitor directly from Studio would work and the view Hierarchy would show in the Monitor, but it will prompt a message “Disable ADB Integration    Following debug sessions will be closed:app”(it says “debug session”, though I am using production build). Notice After I close the Monitor, the “Enable ADB Integration” option will be automatically checked again by Studio.

(b) Opening Monitor from Bash will prompt error message saying “ddms, could not open selected VM debug port(870)”, but simply manually unchecking the “Enable ADB Integration” option will fix the problem and the View Hierarchy will show.

(2) If I didn’t put a check mark on “Enable ADB Integration” option:
    Opening Monitor directly from Studio and from Bash both work, no additional operations needed.

(ii) If it’s debug build:
    I have to enable ADB Integration in order to launching debugging, so “Enable ADB Integration” option will be checked.
    After Studio installed the app in my phone:
    Then the behavior is exactly the same in the section (i)-(1). In other words, for View Hierarchy purpose, launching debug build is the same as launching production build with “Enable ADB Integration” option checked.

In conclusion: To install the app, “Instant Run” need to be unchecked(see instruction in the top of the report). To show View Hierarchy in Monitor, “Enable ADB Integration” need to be unchecked. Opening Monitor from bash and from Studio both work. Debug Build and production build both work.