# Why is hierarchyviewer not working for Samsung Galaxy TAB 7.0?

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I've used hierarachyviewer earlier, but on android emulator. It works absolutely fine when I use it on the emulator. However it does not work with Samsung Galaxy TAB 7.0, with Android 2.3.4.

This is the log, that I get

```
11:04:22 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server version from device 303599
64881B00EC
11:04:22 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server protocol version from devi
ce 30359964881B00EC
11:04:24 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device 30359964881B00EC
11:05:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server version from device 303599
64881B00EC
11:05:05 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server protocol version from devi
ce 30359964881B00EC
11:05:07 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device 30359964881B00EC
11:09:38 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server version from device 303599
64881B00EC
11:09:38 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server protocol version from devi
ce 30359964881B00EC
11:09:40 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device 30359964881B00EC
```

I'm also not using hierarchyviewer in the debug mode, just running the application.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that Samsung customized its android kernel a little too much! I got problems with GSM functions in Galaxy Tab as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hierarchy is not working for my device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801427/hierarchy-is-not-working-for-my-device)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I found a workaround: https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

> ViewServer is a simple class you can use in your Android application to use the HierarchyViewer inspection tool...
>
> - Verify that you need this library([newer versions of Android don't](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html))
>
> If you do need this library then follow these directions:
>
> - Include the ViewServer library(easy directions found [here](https://jitpack.io/#romainguy/ViewServer))
> - Your application must require the INTERNET permission
> - The recommended way to use this API is to register activities when they are created, and to unregister them when they get destroyed:
>
>   ```
>   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           // Set content view, etc.
>           ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
>       }
>
>       public void onDestroy() {
>           super.onDestroy();
>           ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
>       }
>
>       public void onResume() {
>           super.onResume();
>           ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);
>       }
>   }
>   ```
>
> Please refer to the documentation in ViewServer.java for more info...

Comment: ....if you are developing on a device that is NOT developer phone (ie...you bought it from a store or a carrier network) this is the way to go.  Awesome.

Comment: Thanks. You only need too ViewServer.java to your project source and add few methods your code to enable ViewServer. Also add Internet Permission to your manifest.

Comment: If you have Base Activity class for all your Activities it will be very easy to implement.

Answer (score 50):

Use the monitor-tool instead (`android-sdk/tools/monitor`).

Connect to your device. Close Eclipse first if you can't connect.

Press the "Dump view hierarchy for UI automator" button in the devices-tab. Its the one next to the screen-capture button.

Works since API Level 16 (Android 4.1).

Comment: Also available from DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: That's not the same tool at all.

Comment: Wow, this tool should be on all getting started docs for Android.

Answer (score 35):

You can only use HierarachyViewer on the emulator and special developer phones bought from google.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b0b0af7a316ca768

Quote from above link

> HierarchyViewer does not work on user builds (i.e. with devices 
>   available in stores.) This is for security reasons. If HiearchyViewer 
>   was able to work on user builds, any application on your desktop (or 
>   even on the phone in some cases) could potentially get access to 
>   private information (like logins and passwords.)

Comment: Thanks user1378730!! Maybe, I need to buy one. :)

Answer (score 21):

I'm solved question in max os

this ANDROID_HVPROTO solution is documented here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html

then try to close Android Studio

run adb kill-server, adb start-server

and launch monitor work to me!

the answer is :

https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer/issues/14#issuecomment-75354479

@ozodrukh's answer is usefull.

Comment: Hi small silver, Please add ozodurkh's answer with a quotation if you think that is the solution. That will keep your valid even if that URL becomes invalid someday

Comment: Hey how to do this? "Set the environment variable ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm on your development machine."

Answer (score 6):

Almost no general-production phones will allow the HierarchyViewer to access them. Usually developer phones and emulators are the only ones with those features.

Comment: Thanks Srdjan!! Your answer was helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

Similar issue i was having on 4.1 Android phone.Use [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) in your code.

Before checking in Hierarchy viewer,Just restart adb server once by doing.

Answer (score 1):

the official documentation:[Optimizing Your UI](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/optimize-ui.html) said so:

> To preserve security, Hierarchy Viewer can only connect to devices running a developer version of the Android system.

Answer (score 1):

[Profile your layout with Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer):

Set the environment variable

```
ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm
```

So from `[andrid-sdk]/tools` folder run this in Command Line:

```
set ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm
hierarchyviewer
```

Or put `set ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm` in the `hierarchyviewer.bat`.