# Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554 & Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator-5554

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

[image]

Does anyone know about these error messages in Android Studio?

I tried to open the Android Device Monitor with Android Virtual Device (Nexus5, API 26) to see the hierarchy view of the example app, but I can't see the hierarchy view because of the errors below.

```
[2017-08-27 07:56:31 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554
[2017-08-27 07:56:31 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator-5554
[2017-08-27 07:56:31 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: Nexus_5_API_26 [emulator-5554]
[2017-08-27 07:56:32 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for emulator-5554
[2017-08-27 07:56:32 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device emulator-5554
```

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647300/why-is-hierarchyviewer-not-working-for-samsung-galaxy-tab-7-0/10647405 Maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

Windows,add environment：

> ANDROID_HVPRORO:ddm