# Missing forwarded port in Hierarchy Viewer : Using Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, layout, view, hierarchy

I am using Android device monitor in Android Studio to use Hierarchy Viewer.
 I have followed this [link.](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-setup.html) 
Everything else is verified - adb, environment variable , etc.
I get following error:

```
Missing forwarded port for 33002242e81572f9
[2016-10-20 12:29:20 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device 33002242e81572f9
[2016-10-20 12:29:20 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for 33002242e81572f9
[2016-10-20 12:29:20 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device 33002242e81572f9
[2016-10-20 12:29:20 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: sm_t815y-33002242e81572f9
```

I searched for solution but only found [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801427/hierarchy-is-not-working-for-my-device), any help apreciated.

Comment: Maybe consider using the Layout Inspector which is part of Android Studio 2.2+ - just connect your device, open the screen you want to check out, then click on Tools > Android > Layout Inspector - pick the screen you want and a window will open with the details regarding that screen, including layout hierarchy.